# Method of characteristic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I have the PDE given by $u_t+x^2u_x=0$ with the auxiliary condition of $u=\sin(x)$ for $t=0$ and $x>0$. Applying the method of characteristics to solve for $u$ we get the path

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2, x(\epsilon,0)=\epsilon$$

since $\frac{du}{dt}=0$, the PDE reduces to an ODE. From this we get that $u(\epsilon,t)=f(\epsilon)$. Now integrating our path we get.

$$-\frac{1}{x}=t+\epsilon \implies \epsilon = -\frac{1}{x}-t$$

therefore we have $u(x,t)=f\left(-\frac{1}{x}-t\right)$ I can verify the solution with $u_x=\frac{1}{f'}, u_t=t$. Now we know that $u(x,0)= \sin(x)$ thus we get $f(-1/x)= \sin(x)$. This seems wrong to me, can anyone help me here? Where did I do it wrongly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You solved you characteristic equation wrong. To satisfy the initial condition, it should read $\frac{-1}{x} + \frac{1}{\epsilon} = t\implies \epsilon = \frac{x}{tx+1}$.

Comment: ahh, looks like my algebra is rusty. thanks @whpowell96

Comment: Not an algebra issue, just an issue with where the initial condition goes when integrating a separable equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_t+x^2u_x=0$$
$$u(x,t)=f\left(-\frac{1}{x}-t\right)\quad\text{ is OK.}$$
This is the general solution where $f$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the initial condition ).

Initial condition : $\quad u(x,0)=\sin(x)=f\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Let : $X=-\frac{1}{x} \quad\implies\quad x=-\frac{1}{X}$
$$f(X)=\sin\left( -\frac{1}{X}\right)$$
The function $f(X)$ is determined. One put it into the above general solution where $X=-\frac{1}{x}-t$

$$u(x,t)=\sin\left( -\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{x}-t}\right)$$
$$\boxed{u(x,t)=\sin\left(\frac{x}{1+t\,x} \right)}$$
This is the particular solution satisfying both the PDE and the condition.